# Spring boot jpa hibernate not persisting data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist data to database using **spring boot - jpa - hibernate**.

This is my **application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BlurAdmin
spring.datasource.username=blurAdmin
spring.datasource.password =mypassword
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true 
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
c3p0.acquireIncrement=2
c3p0.minPoolSize=10
c3p0.maxPoolSize=20
c3p0.maxIdleTime=5000
c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection=50
c3p0.idle_test_period=30000

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This is **HibernateConfiguration.java:**

```
  @Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }
}
```

This is my  **Model:** There is a warning beside @Entity saying :

> The project doesn't contain persistant unit

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "BlurAdminUsers")
public class User implements Serializable{

      public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;
      private String username;
      private String email;
      private String password;
      private String role;

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

      protected User(){

      }

      public User(String username,String email,String password){
          this.username = username;
          this.password = password;
          this.email = email;
      }



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }




}
```

This is **Repository**:

```
    @Transactional
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByEmail(String email);
    List<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

This is my *aop class where I am trying to persist data:*

```
    @Component
public class Signup {

    private DataValidation dataValidation;
    private Message message;
    private UsersRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public Signup(UsersRepository repository) {
        dataValidation = new DataValidation();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Around("execution(* com.ghewareunigps.vts.ui.web.controllers.SignupController.signup(..)) && args(user,..)")
    public Message validateAndSignup(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, User user) throws Throwable {
         List<User> usersWithEmail = repository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
         List<User> usersWithUsername = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) ;
         user.setRole(Roles.ROLE_USER);
        if (dataValidation.validate(user.getUsername(), user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())) {
              if(usersWithEmail.isEmpty() && usersWithUsername.isEmpty()){
                   message  =  (Message) joinPoint.proceed();
                   try{
                                          repository.save(user);

                   }catch(Exception ex){
                       System.out.println(ex);
                   }
              }
              else{
                  message = new Message(false,"Sorry user with email or username already exists");
              }

        } else {
            message = new Message(false, " please recheck your credentials");
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

There's no exceptions being thrown and I have added all the dependencies. Can some please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you put your business logic into an aspect? Put it in the controller, or in a service called by the controller, and make sure it's transactional.

Comment: The aspect's method signup is attached to pointcut method of the controller! does it make a difference if the logic is in a service or aspect?

Comment: What does the method signup of your controller does if it doesn't even do the signup? Again, why are you using an aspect?

Comment: ok I am persisting the data in controller now!

Comment: I am sorry i am new to spring

Comment: Can you show updated controller method? Did you check your logs for errors? Try setting a breakpoint where error occurs and inspect variable for error. Double check to ensure db constraints are not being violated.

Comment: Your aspect isn't an aspect it should be also annotated with `@Aspect` to be that. Also why on earth an aspect for this? Validation can be easily handled by your controller or should be in your service layer and not hidden in an aspect (it hardly is a cross cutting concern). Yuo shouldn't be persisting data in your controller but in your service layer. Your controller should only be a thin translation layer from http to your actual internal service call. It is basically an adapter.